# How to calculate RGB values from an image with transparent background?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, rgb

I have an image with 4 circles on transparent background. I want to obtain the average RGB and HSV values from those 4 circles. Here is the image:

[1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7e6u.png)
[transparent.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWmod.png)

I tried to obtain the RGB values from that image, but it measured the transparent background as black. Here is the code that I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('1.png')
hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# Min and max HSV value for color thresholding
lower = np.array([140, 0, 180])
upper = np.array([255, 255, 240])
mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

gray = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, alpha = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# Split RGB channels
b, g, r = cv.split(result)

# Making list of Red, Green, Blue, Channels and Alpha
rgba = [b, g, r, alpha]

# Merge RGBA
transparent = cv.merge(rgba, 4)

cv.imwrite('transparent.png', transparent)

b = np.mean(transparent[:,:,0])
g = np.mean(transparent[:,:,1])
r = np.mean(transparent[:,:,2])

print(r,g,b)
```

The result is: 12.373360042366052 9.290387050724137 12.575911215491239

I tried to calculate the RGB values in ImageJ by manually select the ROI and the result is 205.57, 153.62, 209.33. Any kind of help is very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when you use cv.imread() function converts the transparent pixels to black.
To avoid this, you can use the function like this:

```
img = cv.imread('1.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

This will load the image with the alpha channel, which you can then use to separate the image channels:

```
b, g, r, alpha = cv.split(img)
```

Now you can use the alpha channel as a mask to get the RGB values of only the non-transparent pixels:

```
b = np.mean(b[alpha != 0])
g = np.mean(g[alpha != 0])
r = np.mean(r[alpha != 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already very close! One step that is missing is to exclude the background from the mean calculation:

I started with your `transparent.png`:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('transparent.png', cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

# discard the background (intensity 0 => black)
bg_color = 0
img_without_background = img[gray != bg_color]
r_mean, g_mean, b_mean = np.mean(img_without_background, axis=0)
```

which yields:

`R: ~214`

`G: ~158`

`B: ~210`